# Function signature for AWS Lambda Callback

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda

I wanted to create a Typescript for AWS Lambda's callback function and must be doing something dumb because I'm getting errors on something that seems easy. The way I'm approaching it is to have two function definitions for a SUCCESS and FAILURE condition and then to wrap them together as a *discriminated union*.

So here are my types:

```
export interface ILambdaSuccessCallback<T = IDictionary> {
  (error: null, response: T): void;
}

export interface ILambdaFailureCallback<E = ILambdaErrorResponse> {
  (error: string | number, response: E): void;
}

export interface ILambdaErrorResponse<T = any> {
  errorCode?: string | number;
  message?: string;
  errors?: T[];
  stackTrace?: string[];
}

/** Discriminated Union */
export type LambdaCallback<T = IDictionary, E = ILambdaErrorResponse> =
  | LambdaSuccessCallback<T>
  | LambdaFailureCallback<E>;
```

I've now included my little visual test in vs-code showing the behavior or explicit use of *failure* and *success* but also, more importantly, the discriminated union which is just not working:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union types (defined with `|`) represent a type that can be either `ILambdaSuccessCallback` or `ILambdaFailureCallback` which means that neither signature is callable because the compiler can't check which is valid. With union types you only have access to common fields and signatures and `ILambdaSuccessCallback` and `ILambdaFailureCallback` have no properties or signatures in common,

If your function can handle both signatures you want an intersection type (defined with `&`)

```
export type LambdaCallback<T = IDictionary, E = ILambdaErrorResponse> =
    & ILambdaSuccessCallback<T>
    & ILambdaFailureCallback<E>;

const either: LambdaCallback = function (err: null | string | number, con: IDictionary | ILambdaErrorResponse) {

}
either(null, {}) // Works
either(500, {}) // Works
```

The second `failure` call (`failure(null, {})`) works, because in Typescript, `null` and `undefined` are subtypes of all types (see the [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#326-the-null-type)) and thus you can assign `null` to `string | number` you can enable `strictNullChecks` to make the compiler forbid this scenario (but this might cause a lot of other warnings)

Comment: Yay! That seems to be the solution!

Comment: @ken added more detail about the failure call which is a different issue